# What is wrong with my import/export class code lines?

Tags: javascript, import, html5-canvas, export

I'm in the midst of working on a brick breaker game, and although my code works on CodeSandbox, when I try it on a local computer the import function doesn't work, and along with it, the game.

I've tried moving the folders around, researched how to do so and tried adding {} around the class names, but to no avail.

This is my index.html script link

```
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

This is in my index.js file (in folder 'src')

```
import Game from "/src/game.js";
```

This is what 'Game' is in my game.js file (also in folder 'src').

```
export default class Game {
  constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    this.gamestate = GAMESTATE.MENU;
    this.paddle = new Paddle(this);
    this.ball = new Ball(this);
    this.gameObjects = [];
    new InputHandler(this.paddle, this);
  }
```

In CodeSandbox, there is no problem with the game, as it functions perfectly normal whereas when I run it locally, the console reads "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Game'. import call expects exactly one argument." and the canvas is blank. I've been stuck on this for a while and really need some help.

Comment: Try embrace the class declaration with parenthesis: `export default (class Game { ... })`

Comment: is the path to game correct ? it should be `"./game.js";`

Answer (score 0):

```
import Game from './game';
```

It's more usual to export the modules in the index.js files
So, you can try the following:

```
export Game from './game';
```